# An universal way to set unicode cookies in Python

Tags: python, http, cookies

Only the first word is saved into a cookie using an "example" code if there is a space in value.

What is a really correct, unicode-compatible way to make that?

```
response.headers.add_header(
  'Set-Cookie',
  '%s=%s; expires:Sun, 31-May-2020 23:59:59 GMT; path=/;' % (key, value))
```

UPD. A solution is below

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html

Comment: Haha. I feel like I'm the first human who need to set a cookie correctly. The Cookie.SimpleCookie class produces 'Set-Cookie' part while App Engine don't want that.

Comment: Please keep reading.  http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#Cookie.Morsel.coded_value might be what you're looking for.  It's impossible to tell from the question what code you have and what error you're getting.

Comment: OutputString() is the goal. Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#Cookie.Morsel.OutputString

Comment: It is not unicode compatible however. I receive UnicodeEncodeError setting a cookie with it. It seems I should do that by hands.

Comment: Are you asking about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875313/unicode-cookie-value

Comment: JFYI, urllib.quote(key) fails with KeyError: u'\u041f' on an unicode string

Comment: value.encode('unicode-escape') works better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the job is done:

1. cookies escaped with Cookie.SimpleCookie
2. unescaped with custom code
3. unicode encoded/decoded with string's encode/decode

The code:

```
import Cookie
def set_unicode_cookie(response, key, value):
  c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
  c[key] = value.encode('unicode-escape')
  c[key]["expires"] = "Sun, 31-May-2020 23:59:59 GMT"
  c[key]["path"] = "/"
  response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', c[key].OutputString())

def get_unicode_cookie(request, key, defult_value):
  def unescape(s):
    m = re.match(r'^"(.*)"$', s)
    s = m.group(1) if m else s
    return s.replace("\\\\", "\\")
  if request.cookies.has_key(key):
    return unescape(request.cookies[key]).decode('unicode-escape')
  else:
    return default_value
```